# using union all in ordered query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on this query that requires both, sorted rows (order by) and the union statement. What I want to do is get the latest reading according to time for each customer. I know I can not use order by within union statements, but is there any way to achieve what I want? I also have a few tables joined withing the select statement. The following is my sample query:

```
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0001' 
(order by Time desc)
union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0002' 
(order by Time desc)
union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0003' 
(order by Time desc)
```

So I am looking for something that would yield these results. Does anyone know of such method?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a classic [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. In SQL Server 2005 or later version, it is solved easily with the help of the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time DESC)
  FROM Table1
  JOIN Table2 ON ID = Cust_ID
  JOIN Table3 ON c = d
  WHERE ID = 'ID0001'
)
SELECT name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
FROM ranked
WHERE ID IN ('ID0001', 'ID0002', 'ID0003')
  AND rnk = 1
```

That is, using `ROW_NUMBER()`, rank rows in every group of rows with the same `ID` in the descending order of `Time`, then pick those with the top rankings and belonging to specific groups (i.e. having specific `ID` values).

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is put the order by clause at the end of the entire query.

```
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0001' 

union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0002' 

union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID
from Table1
join Table2
on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3
on c = d
where ID = 'ID0003' 
order by ID, Time desc
```

**Edited explanation**

Note the change I made in the above Order by clause. It will first order by ID in ascending order then by the Customer's Time in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for you response Eric. You are right, putting order by at the end only will work. However, that is not what I need. I need each select statement to be ordered by time in order to get the most recent reading from each customer.

Comment: @Rick, please see my edited version. Note that I added ID to the Order By clause. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID from Table1
join Table2 on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3 on c = d
where ID = 'ID0001' 
union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID from Table1
join Table2 on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3 on c = d
where ID = 'ID0002' 
union all
select  top 1 name, ID, Date, Time, Cust_ID from Table1
join Table2 on ID = Cust_ID
join Table3 on c = d
where ID = 'ID0003')
order by ID, Time desc
```

Comment: You don't really need the select * From and everything else in parenthesis. The Order by at the end will order Time from all queries.

Comment: I see what you mean, but you can still put parenthesis around the entire select statment excluding the Order By Clause to make it LESS obscured and more readable

Comment: @srini.venigalla, I understand the what you have done with the parenthesis. However, this still simply sorts the customers based on time only, without considering the latest reading. This is why I need to order each select statement by time first before using the union statement.

Comment: @Rick, then you order by ID first and then Time